# React Auto Complete value propblem

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, label

So the autocomplete work displays option of diffrent countries and their flag icons as well ,saving data to a database also work ,the problem im having is when I want to display the value (on edit mode) it
dowant show except when I remove the "getOptionLabel" from the autoComplete also whould like to add a flag Icon to the value as well

```
<Autocomplete
            /*value={values.country+ 
                 <Avatar
                style={{ height: 42, width: 42 }}
                src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${values.flag}`}
            ></Avatar>}*/
                name="country"

                options={countryData}
                getOptionLabel={option => option.listDescription}
                onChange={(e, value) => {
                    setFieldValue(
                        'country',
                        value !== null ? value.listDescription : 'country'
                    );

                    setFieldValue('region', value !== null ? value.region : 'region');
                    setFieldValue('flag', value !== null ? value.image.data : 'flag');
            //console.log( value.image.data)
                }}
                renderInput={params => (
                    <TextField
                        {...params}
                        error={Boolean(touched.country && errors.country)}
                        helperText={touched.country && errors.country}
                        name="country"
                        label="Select Country"
                        variant="outlined"
                        onChange={(e, value) => setFieldValue('country', value)} 
                        onBlur={() => setFieldTouched('country', true)}
                        fullWidth
                        value={values.country+
                         <Avatar
                            style={{ height: 42, width: 42 }}
                            src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${values.flag}`}
                        ></Avatar>}
                    />
                )}
                renderOption={option => (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <img
                            style={{ height: 30, width: 30 }}
                            src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${option.image.data}`}
                        ></img>{' '}
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        {option.listDescription}
                    </React.Fragment>
                )}
            />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const CountryComponent = (props) =>
{
    const countrySelected = useRef(null);
    const [externalData, setExternalData] = useState(null);
    const [foundCountry, setFoundCountry] = useState(null);


    let captureForm = useFormikContext();

    // check if the form value has changed
    if (captureForm.values != null && captureForm.values.country != null && captureForm.values.country != '')
        countrySelected.current = captureForm.values.country;

    let findCountry = function(data)
    {
        // routine to set the country when the list initialized or the value changes
        if (data != null && countrySelected.current != null)
        {
            setFoundCountry(data.find(element => element.listCode === countrySelected.current));
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        // make the request to get the country data (this only happens once)
        let asyncRequest = null;
        function getData() {
            asyncRequest = Api('country/all', 'Get').then(
                externalData => {
                    asyncRequest = null;

                    // force the render
                    setExternalData(externalData);
                    findCountry(externalData);
                }
            );
        }

        getData();
        return function cleanup() {
            // cleanup the async request as on component deallocation - this will be run by useEffect as its the returning function
            if (asyncRequest) {
                asyncRequest.cancel();
            }
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        // determine the selected country once the form is re-rendered (this will only be called if the value changes)
        findCountry(externalData);
    }, [countrySelected.current]);

    return externalData ?
        (
            <div>
                <Autocomplete
                    name="country"
                    options={externalData}
                    getOptionLabel={option => option.listDescription}
                    value={foundCountry}
                    getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.listCode === value.listCode}
             
                    onChange={(e, value) => {
                        if (value != null)
                        {
                            captureForm.setFieldValue('country', value.listCode);
                            captureForm.setFieldValue('region', value.region);
                            captureForm.setFieldValue('flag', value.image.data);
                            
                        }
                    }}
                    renderInput={params => (
                        <TextField
                            {...params}
                            error={Boolean(captureForm.touched.country && captureForm.errors.country)}
                            helperText={captureForm.touched.country && captureForm.errors.country}
                            name="country"
                            label="Select Country"
                            variant="outlined"
                            onChange={(e, value) => captureForm.setFieldValue('country', value)} /**/
                            onBlur={() => captureForm.setFieldTouched('country', true)}
                            fullWidth
                        />
                    )}
                    renderOption={option => (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <img
                                style={{height: 30, width: 30}}
                                src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${option.image.data}`}
                            ></img>{' '}
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            {option.listDescription}
                        </React.Fragment>
                    )}
                />
            </div>
        ) :
        (
            <div>Loading...</div>
        );
```